# Controlling kodi on raspbian remotely through ssh

Tags: raspbian, ssh, kodi

I installed Raspbian-lite on my Raspberry Pi 3 and then kodi on top of it. I have my raspberry pi hooked up into my television.

I can successfully ssh into Raspbian through my laptop and I can start kodi remotely as well through the ssh session.

However, although kodi appears in my television, it won't recognize my laptop's keyboard. In other words I can't use my laptop to navigate kodi remotely.

I was wondering if there was a way to control kodi remotely through ssh, using Raspbian as an OS.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't supposed to work. Would you consider Android and Apple remote control apps instead ? Like Yatse ?

Comment: Let's put it in another way. What's the most efficient way of controlling raspbian-lite + kodi without having to leave my couch and my laptop?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to redirect a remote computer that can act as a STDIN (keyboard) over the network.

Example uinput-mapper.

http://blog.pi3g.com/2014/03/uinput-mapper-redirecting-keyboard-and-mouse-to-any-linux-system-using-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: The link is now dead but there may be something similar around if you search for "linux uinput keyboard network".

Answer (score 1):

After ssh, run kodi-remote. I will allow you to control Kodi through keyboard